# jQuery .load() behaviour

Tags: jquery

I'm implementing a website with a main screen with nested divs and subsequent pages are loaded in a secondary div with the `.load()` function.

In order to avoid multiple and overlapping functions is it fine to load a page with the `.load()` function or should I first clear the previously loaded contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, `.load()` always replaces the contents of your element(s) based on your selector i.e. `.hello-world`

> When a successful response is detected, `.load()` sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the
>   returned data.

from https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

If you want make effect during the page load you need to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your functions that you want to call on pageload
});
```

If you want to give effect after page content load like some images etc. you need to use

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // your functions that you want to call after pageload
});
```

Comment: I think the OP is referring to `.load()` as in the shorthand ajax method not the `.load()` event handler.